# ClojureScript Leiningen compile to a single .js file?

Tags: javascript, build, clojure, leiningen, clojurescript

Can Leiningen be configured in such way that it bundles all compiled JS to a single file? Currently it outputs over a hundred files, which would be very slow in production.

I'm using [Chestnut boilerplate](https://github.com/plexus/chestnut/), by the way. The documentation says:

> Q: I just want to compile ClojureScript to fully optimized JavaScript, so I can use it in a static HTML site.
>
> A: Invoke cljsbuild with the uberjar profile active, like this: `lein with-profile -dev,+uberjar cljsbuild once`, then look for `resources/public/js/app.js`.

I've tried it, but the resulting `app.js` is still just loads the dependencies from other files, it doesn't contain the whole app.

Comment: How does your `project.clj` look like? You are probably using `:optimization :none`. https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Compiler-Options#optimizations

Comment: Add another `[:cljsbuilds :builds ...]` to your map with `optimization :advanced`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `lein with-profile -dev,+uberjar cljsbuild once` does generate a single .js bundle. `:uberjar` profile already has `:optimizations :advanced` option set in:

```
:uberjar {:source-paths ["env/prod/clj"]
                       :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild]
                       :env {:production true}
                       :omit-source true
                       :aot :all
                       :main calc-pack.server
                       :cljsbuild {:builds {:app
                                            {:source-paths ["env/prod/cljs"]
                                             :compiler
                                             {:optimizations :advanced
                                              :pretty-print false}}}}}
```

Apparently, it wasn't working properly because of errors in my own code.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments: make sure you use one of the following `:optimizations`:

- `:whitespace`
- `:simple`
- `:advanced`

You can find more information in the ClojureScript wiki:
https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Compiler-Options#optimizations